# How to use LabelFor on a strongly typed view for a list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

When I used asp.net mvc 3 scaffolding to make a list. I got a view containing a table. With the headers of that table hard coded in the view. I want to use LabelFor, so I get the l10n I need.

What I tried to do (but failed) was:

```
@model IEnumerable<User>
<table>
 <tr>
   <th>
      @(Html.LabelFor<User, string>(model => model.Name)) <!--This line errors-->
   </th>
 </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
 <td>
  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
 </td>
</table>
```

It errors with "IEnumerable does not contain a definition for Name".. etc...

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try with some like

```
@(Html.LabelFor<User, string>(model => model.FirstOrDefault().Name))
```

Comment: Wouldn't this mean that I get a NullReferenceException when the list is empty?

Comment: Nop. If it's empty, you will obtain the right label anyway. The trick is using FirstOrDefault intead of just First. Try it! :D Note that it will work if the list is empty, but not if the list is null. I think it's exactly what you need. I use this way everyday.

Comment: You're right. This is perfect, and saves me from writing extra code (viewModel) and resources :D. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Close, but it would have to be:
@(Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().Name))

Comment: I agree it should be @(Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().Name))   pending the correct type of IEnumerable  ( ViewModel etc..)

Comment: Great voodoo!  Thanks for this tip.  LabelFor on a simple table layout is much easier now.

Comment: @Jonathan, just as an FYI, the trick is not using `FirstOrDefault`.  The magic trick is that the whole lambda is passed in as an `Expression<Func<TModel, TResult>>` which never actually evaluates the delegate, just passes an expression tree, full of rich, sweet metadata.  `FirstOrDefault` returns `null` if the collection is empty anyway, which would not be a good starting point for finding the DisplayAttribute of a particular property on an *object reference not set to an instance of an object*.  You could use `model[93].Name` and it would still work inside of `DisplayFor`

Answer (score 4):

Your view model is not adapted to what you are trying to achieve. Here's how a better view model would look like:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    // This property represents the header value
    // you could use data annotations to localize it
    [Display(.. some localization here ..)]
    public string NameHeader { get; set; }

    // This property represents the data source that 
    // will be used to build the table
    public IEnumerable<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
@model MyViewModel
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.NameHeader)
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model.Users) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and with a display template you don't even need to write a `foreach` loop:

```
@model MyViewModel
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.NameHeader)
        </th>
    </tr>
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Users)
</table>
```

and inside the custom display template (`~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/User.cshtml`):

```
@model User
<tr>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Name)</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the extensive answer. I'm gonna try and see if I can fit this in :-)

Comment: +1 for the info on display templates and the insight of creating a more specific ViewModel. But I went with the easier alternative of Jonathan

Comment: @Diring Dimitrov .. You are simply awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Use DisplayNameFor instead 
**@Html.DisplayNameFor(model =>model.Name)**

Comment: After further review, this appears to be the best solution. `DisplayNameFor` will detect `IEnumerable` types and automatically adjust the expression signature so that you can use the collection's item type instead of the collection type (as shown in this answer). Does anyone have a reason why one should avoid `DisplayNameFor` in favor of `LaborFor`?

Answer (score 0):

You render the Label before (or outside) of the foreach iteration, thus you try to access Name property in an IEnumerable collection which doesn't exist.

Comment: Well, I thought by explicitly specifying the generic types of the LabelFor method, I'd get to use the `User` Model (wich is what I wan't). But that apparently isn't possible, since `Html` is of type `HtmlHelper<T>` wich takes the same generic parameter as the View itself (`IEnumerable<User>`). And I guess I can't change that.