# LabelFor not working in loop (for/foreach/template)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to make a list of checkboxes but the Html.LabelFor is not working.
It keeps generating `<label for="">Some text</label>`, note the empty `For` attribute.

I've tried a for and foreach loop before I tried using a display template but they all have this problem.
I refuse to believe that writing the input fields by hand is the only solution.
All help/tips are much appreciated.

### The Model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

### The Controller:

```
public ActionResult MyController()
{
    var model = new List<MyViewModel>();

    model.Add(new MyViewModel() { Name= "Foo" });
    model.Add(new MyViewModel() { Name= "Bar" });

    return View(model);
}
```

### The View:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyViewModel>
<div>
    @Html.DisplayFor(x => Model)
</div>
```

### The Display Template:

```
@model MyViewModel
<p>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Selected, Model.Name)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Selected)
</p>
```

### The Result:

```
<div>    
    <p>
        <label for="">Foo</label>
        <input class="check-box" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Foo field is required." 
            name="[0].Selected" type="checkbox" value="true" />
        <input name="[0].Selected" type="hidden" value="false" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="">Bar</label>
        <input class="check-box" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Bar field is required." 
            name="[1].Selected" type="checkbox" value="true" />
        <input name="[1].Selected" type="hidden" value="false" />
    </p>
<div>
```

As you can see the `<label>` isn't working as intended.

Comment: I think I've narrowed it down to the EditorFor() doesn't generate an id attribute so the LabelFor() has nothing to attach to.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The thing is that since in your main view you directly have `IEnumerable<MyViewModel>`, the prefix is `[0].Selected` which the helpers doesn't like. You will also notice that your checkbox doesn't have an id. Here's a hack that you could employ to change this prefix:

```
@model MyViewModel
@{
    ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = "Model" + ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix;
}

<p>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Selected, Model.Name)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Selected)
</p>
```

Obviously this assumes that your POST action argument is called `model`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<MyViewModel> model) { ... }
```

which might not always be the case.

Also note that instead of `@Html.DisplayFor(x => Model)` in your main view you could use `@Html.EditorForModel()`.

Another possibility is to wrap this in a view model with a collection property:

public class MyViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable Items { get; set; }
}

where `ItemViewModel`:

```
public class ItemViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

and then your controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel
    {
        Items = new[]
        {
            new ItemViewModel() { Name= "Foo" },
            new ItemViewModel() { Name= "Bar" }
        }
    };
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
{
    ...
}
```

and in the view:

```
@model MyViewModel
<div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Items)
        <button type="submit">OK</button>
    }
</div>
```

and in the editor template (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/ItemViewModel.cshtml`):

```
@model ItemViewModel
<p>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Selected, Model.Name)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Selected)
</p>
```

Now it will work as expected.

Comment: This looks interesting, I'll give it a go :)

Comment: It works! Many thanks. 
I ended up using the example with the enumerable in the model as it seemed like the more solid solution.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov .. I have also seen same stuff for display purpose on the following link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6703353/how-to-use-labelfor-on-a-strongly-typed-view-for-a-list) . I just have a question, What should be name of the cshtml? (Is it same as a Model name or something else).

Answer (score 0):

why are you using the model.Selected in

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Selected, Model.Name)
```

wouldn't below code work?

```
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
```

Comment: It doesn't :(
Also how would the LabelFor know what to attach itself to? I believe I have to use the same property in both the editor and label for it to be linked.

Comment: Have you tried using a foreach in your view? @foreach(model in Model){@Html.DisplayFor(model)}

Comment: That actually somewhat worked. But then I lose the unique name of the elements.
So instead of name="[#].Selected" I'm getting name="Selected". Which is a problem when I POST.

Answer (score 0):

write the foreach as

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
```

and then you can bind like this

```
  Html.DisplayFor(model => model[i].Name)
  Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].Name)
```

You should be able to post this then.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to Darin Dimitrov.

One more thing to add:

The names must match in other way it does not recognize it as the model. (for this example mySkills)

ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = "**mySkills**" + ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix;...

public ActionResult Create(List **mySkills** ...