# About MVC ViewModel and partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel, partial-views

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to edit multiple models in a single Razor View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10720756/how-to-edit-multiple-models-in-a-single-razor-view)

I'm using MVC3 to make an order functionality. I have Order and OrderDetail Model. Order and OrderDetail is in an one to many relationship.
The two models look something like this:

```
public class order
{
    public int OrderId{get;set;}
    public int OrderStatusID { get; set; } 

    public virtual OrderStatus OrderStatus { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }

}

 public  class OrderDetail
 {
    public int OrderDetailID { get; set; }
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; } 
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }   
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

}
```

I want to use them both in a view, so I made the OrderViewModel for it below,

```
public class OrderViewModel
{
    public virtual Order Order { get;set; }
    public virtual List<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get;set; }
}
```

I have two questions:

1, How can I use the OrderViewModel to make pages for creating and editing Order?
I made the partial view for the OrderDetail. In the Creating page, I did something like the following, but I don't think it's correct.

```
@foreach (var detail in Model.OrderDetails)
{
    @Html.Partial("_OrderDetail", detail)  
}
```

2, Order and OrderDetail is in an one to many relationship, in the creating Order page, I want users to be able to add multiple OrderDetail. I used jQuery to make a button that can make multiple OrderDetail fields, but I don't know how to Retrieve the values from every OrderDetail.

How is this done?

Answer (score 0):

Use `EditorFor` for the details.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look of below link and see an answer of **Darin Dimitrov**

[How to use LabelFor on a strongly typed view for a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6703353/how-to-use-labelfor-on-a-strongly-typed-view-for-a-list/6703629#comment14358804_6703629)

[LabelFor not working in loop (for/foreach/template)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9359089/labelfor-not-working-in-loop-for-foreach-template/9360884#comment14358792_9360884)

Do let me know if you still have any query.